# What is SQL Server 'IN' Clause Equivalent To

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

When we write:

```
SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE Username in ('user1', 'user2', 'user3')
```

is this equivalent to:

```
SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE Username = 'user1' OR Username = 'User2' OR Username = 'User3'
```

Moreover, can we provide the `like` pattern functionality (`%`) to the `IN` clause?

Comment: Respectively, yes and no.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Are they equivalent?
```

**Ans**: Yes

But I would prefer using `IN` clause as it is more readable then `OR` clause in case of large number of values.

> can we provide the like pattern functionality (%) to the IN clause

**Ans**: No

You can't use like operation with `IN` clause. If you want pattern option than you can use `OR` using like operator.

Answer (score 0):

I would use "in" when dealing with multivalued parameters.  Otherwise, there's not much of a difference, just preference.

To your second question:  No, you'll have to use

```
WHERE Username LIKE '%1'
OR Username LIKE '%2'
OR Username LIKE '%3'
...
etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is and no you can't. You could consider using full text search, multiple like with OR as in your question or CASE

Answer (score 0):

The closer you can get to something similar to `IN` for:

```
SELECT u.* 
FROM Users AS u 
WHERE u.Username LIKE 'Mar%'
   OR u.Username LIKE 'Ant%'
   OR u.Username LIKE '%Geo%' 
   OR u.Username LIKE '%arc' ;
```

is by using (the proprietary to SQL-Server) `CROSS APPLY`:

```
SELECT u.* 
FROM Users AS u
  CROSS APPLY
  ( SELECT TOP (1) v.val
    FROM ( VALUES 
             ('Mar%'), ('Ant%'), ('%Geo%'), ('%arc')  
         ) AS v (val)
    WHERE u.Username LIKE v.val 
  ) AS x ;
```

Tested at **[SQL-Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d4b8d/22)**

---

One benefit that you can't do with `IN` or `LIKE ... OR` is that you can have rows from the basic table returned more than one time, if they have more than one match:

```
SELECT u.*, x.val AS MatchingString 
FROM Users AS u
  CROSS APPLY
  ( SELECT v.val
    FROM ( VALUES 
             ('Mar%'), ('Ant%'), ('%Geo%'), ('%arc') 
         ) AS v (val)
    WHERE u.Username LIKE v.val  
  ) AS x ;
```